# I want to get execution time from task_struct

Tags: linux, linux-kernel, task

In a module I am accessing the task_struct and returning with stime+utime.
I want to convert it to milliseconds. In what format stime and utime will be present in task_struct.
I can also access it from /proc//stat. Are the both unit are different.

Answer (score 3):

Advanced Unix Programming by Marc Rochkind covers this topic to some degree (page 55-ish, if I remember correctly). Pardon me if I paraphrase what he states better.

utime represents user time, and is the time spent executing instructions. It is CPU time only and doesn't include time spent waiting to run.

stime is the CPU time spent executing system calls on behalf of the process.

the units are in clock ticks.

clock ticks per second can be determined with the sysconf system call.

I hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

Given a `task_struct`, the total on-cpu time in nanonseconds is stored in `task->se.sum_exec_runtime`.

This does not appear to add up to `task->utime+task->stime` unless first adjusted via `task_cputime_adjusted(task, &utime, &stime)`.

For anyone else trying to implement this kind of functionality, I highly recommend reading `proc(5)`. In this case, searching for `utime` leads you to `/proc/[pid]/stat` (or `proc/self/stat`) which provides `utime` in its 14th column. The implementation can be found in `fs/proc/array.c` which is where I found the call to `task_cputime_adjusted`. Verify module output against e.g. `/proc/[pid]/stat | awk '{ print $14 }` for `utime`.